# custom string before controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

### My goal is to put e.g. USERNAME before all other routes like this:

https://my.exaple.com/USERNAME/controller/function/val1/val2

My site is already running with aprox 50 routes.
I know i have to put into routes.php something like this:

```
$route[(:any)/controller]
```

but that means rewrite all redirects in controllers.

I would not like to rewrite them, to add this quite small feature.

Is possible to pass this parameter somehow dynamically, so I would have not to change all my controllers?

Comment: can you be tried to change the base URL. You can add this like "$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/ABC/";  
and then move your project directory to this folder named ABC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add USERNAME to **all** redirects, you can create custom url helper, taking it from `system/helpers/url_helper.php` and modifying the `redirect` function (pseudocode):

```
if ( ! function_exists('redirect'))
{
    ...

    // Let's add here username to the start of the url
    $uri = get_instance()->user_model->get_username() . "/" . $uri;

    switch ($method)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $code);
            break;
    }

    ...

}
```